# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns different results based on command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, command-line-arguments

I'm hoping someone can explain why **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()** returns different results based on how I pass my command line arguments to the application (running with args vs dragging a folder over the app.exe)

To jump right into it consider this piece of code:

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The current directory is {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        if(args != null && args.Any())
            Console.WriteLine("Command line arguments are {0}", String.Join(", ", args));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you build and run this using the command prompt as shown below the output is what you'd expect. It will output the current directory the application resides in.

```
C:\Projects\ArgumentTest\ApplicationA\bin\Debug\ApplicationA.exe C:\mydirectory
The current directory is C:\Projects\ArgumentTest\ApplicationA\bin\Debug\
Command line arguments are C:\mydirectory
```

If you build and run this program by dragging files or folders over the application you get different results. Instead of returning the expected result instead Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns the path to the first file you've dragged over the application.

I've currently got a work around for this issue however, I am keen to understand why this is happening.

Other info:

- .NET 4.5
- Windows 2012R2 (Virtual machine)
- Full administrator rights on the machine

Hopefully someone can provide some insight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem here is your expectation. In particular, this bit:

> It will output the current directory the application resides in.

That is **not** what I expect from `GetCurrentDirectory()`. The current directory is a feature of the calling context, not the application. If I run the executable via a full or relative path (rather than just `foo.exe`), I expect `GetCurrentDirectory()` to return the directory *that I am in* - not the directory that the application is in. In the case of dragging files over it: frankly, `GetCurrentDirectory()` is largely undefined, but the directory of the first file is not unreasonable.

Comment: +1. Might be useful to add that if the desired behavior is to get the EXE's containing folder, it might be useful to mention using Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName or Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to get that information.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I guess I didn't fully understand the GetDirectory() as I've never really called if from outside my running application.

Answer (score 4):

When you drop a file on to the executable, it will run it from the location of the file you've dropped. For example if you drop C:\Path-To-File\File.txt on to C:\Program\ApplicationA.exe it's like you've done the following from a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Path-To-File
C:\Program\ApplicationA.exe C:\Path-To-File\File.txt
```

When you run the application manually (in your example above) you've got control over the directory it's running from which is why it matches what you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

I bet the problem is the 'Current Directory' property that is different.

**Current directory gives you the current working directory and not where the executable is.**

When you drag&drop the current directory is set to the source (the drag source) and not the drop target