# C# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows form app with the following part of code when the Form Loads

```
public MonitorMail()
{           
    InitializeComponent();

    pathfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    pathfile = pathfile + @"\Log\Configuration.txt";

    var Lista = LoadConfigFile.LoadConfig(pathfile);

    if (Lista.Count > 0)
    {                
        SwithMailText.Text = Lista[0];
        Excel_Textbox.Text = Lista[1];
        LogFileText.Text = Lista[2];
        MailServerText.Text = Lista[3];
        FromText.Text = Lista[4];
        SslText.Text = Lista[5];
        UserText.Text = Lista[6];                
    }
}
```

As you can see in this code i declare a List named as "Lista" which List takes the records of the Configuration file and fill some `textboxes` with the data of that Configuration file.

My problem is the following: when I run my program inside in Visual Studio, it loads the records correctly in those `textboxes`.

When I run my program runs outside of Visual Studio, it also loads the records correctly

**BUT**

When I try run my program from the command prompt (because this how it should be run) like `MonitorMail.exe` the program runs but does not show the data in the textboxes.

After trying to understand why is this happening I noticed that is has something to do with

```
pathfile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

I concluded to that because I changed the `pathfile` to `pathfile="complete path of the Configuration.txt"` so when I hit it from `cmd` works as it should be.

Any idea why `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` affects `cmd`? Or is something am I missing?

Comment: why don't you change this to use `DirectoryInfo` and from there do `FileInfo[]` and you can get a specific file you are looking for to process.
store the BasePath in your app.config file.. 
if not.. then you need to understand that GetCurrentDirectory looks at where the Application that Launches the process resides... for example when you run your application in the debugger it looks at the `Bin` Directory

Comment: @MethodMan I use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` because my app is gonna used in different PC so i need for every PC to get current directory where my configuration file is

Comment: I found solution to my problem i followed the answers in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734363/directory-getcurrentdirectory-returns-different-results-based-on-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in the comments: *"i need for every PC to get current directory that my .exe is"*, but that is not what `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does...

You need

`string myPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;`

instead. That gives you the full path including the file name. You can take the Location's `Directory` if that is what you need.

Comment: sorry i meant where my `configuration file` is...Because from this file i load data