# Why does the program point to the wrong path?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `WPF + MVVMlight.`

I Create a class called 'JSON', and create an instance in SimpleIOC.

Get the path by using Path.GetFullPath in 'JSON' constructor.

The program works fine. However, an intellisense error occurs in App.xaml.

`"vm: ViewModelLocator x: Key = "Locator" d: IsDataSource = "True"` is underlined and the following error occurs.

> "Could not find file 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\Count\Setting.json'."

Isn't Path.GetFullPath a function that gets the path of the current executable file?
Why should there be a file in the path 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\Count\Setting.json'?

When I remove "Path.GetFullPath (" Setting.json ");" from JSON class, IntelliSense error disappears in App.xaml.

oh! one more thing, Even when `MainWindow.xaml` is opened, the same error occurs in App.xaml.

my solution folder path is "C:\Users\john\Desktop\Count".

my excution file path is "C:\Users\john\Desktop\Count\Count\bin".

In App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Count.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Count" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
             StartupUri="3.Driverlayer/MainWindow.xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Count">
  <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
     </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In ViewModelLocator.cs

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        ////{
        ////    // Create design time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Create run time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        ////}

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISettingRead, JSON>(true);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

In JSON.cs

```
    class JSON : ISettingRead
    {
        string _path;
        string _jsonString;
        JObject jsonobj;

        public JSON()
        {
            _path = Path.GetFullPath("Setting.json");
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_path))
            {
                _jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            jsonobj = JObject.Parse(_jsonString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [AppContext.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory) or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` (same as the former) or `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`. It depends on what starts your app. If you don't know, avoid `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and such.

Comment: "Why should there be a file in the path 'C: \ Users \ john \ Desktop \ Count \ Setting.json'" Path.GetFullPath(string) returns relative to the working directory of the current process. Your sln file or project folder is probably on desktop "Count" and the working folder for VS is this location thus (however unexpected) the intellisense failure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734363/directory-getcurrentdirectory-returns-different-results-based-on-command-line

Comment: If the folder containing sln is different from the folder containing executable files, is there a way to get the folder containing executable files?